# Java Object Recognition Image with OpenCv

Tags: java, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and can't find A good example with java for object recognition , I need code to recognize image with image file in command line (no GUI) with good explanation about what happening in the code , I see the source code [here](https://github.com/mesutpiskin/opencv-object-detection/blob/master/src/DeepNeuralNetwork/DnnProcessor.java)

But the error shows

```
    CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
]
    at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.blobFromImage_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.blobFromImage(Dnn.java:88)
    at mehritco.ir.image.opencv.DeepNeuralNetworkProcessor.getObjectsInFrame(DeepNeuralNetworkProcessor.java:96)
    at mehritco.ir.image.opencv.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
]
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imwrite_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imwrite(Imgcodecs.java:501)
    at mehritco.ir.image.opencv.Application.main(Application.java:30)
```

Comment: Can you share  your code, probably there is a problem about reading your *image Mat data* ? *resize* and *imwrite* functions are taking no image or wrong image.

Comment: i found my problem about laptop camera ! i give permission to java to use camera and the code work fine , oh  i write about the code and give a link about it, I use the  source code